# Persist data on the server NextJs

Tags: next.js, next.js13

If I would like to persist some data from a fetch and access it in RSC and middleware. How could I achieve this?

I have tried with Zustand which works for RSC's but in the middleware it don't.

I have looked in to `react cache` but it works only in components according to their docs.
I also have checked nextJs `unstable_cache` but that also won't work in the middleware.

To give some context, I want to store user data like Culture, Roles, Permissions etc. after a InitalData fetch. For the client I use `react context` and that does the job for the client.

Some help in how you would approach this would be much appriciated!

Comment: You want to validate the user's permission in the middleware before the request reaches the api interface right?  you want to achieve this by using nextauth or nextjs server api.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, its complicated :D. But I will use nextAuth in the future. But in this case in the middleware I want to use the culture to set correct searchParam. In the RSC I want to check some permisson. And in another RSC I want to display the userName. Thats why I need to store this info somehow and be able to accsses this from anywhere on the NextJs server.